# How to use a string enum with a method as a generic parameter?

Tags: go, generics

I have multiple string-derived enums that share a common `Validate()` method (all outside of my control). I would like a generic method that converts a string to those enums and calls `Validate()` on the resulting enum. I've tried to achieve this with generics but failed for various reasons.

In the example below the type constrained is too strong and prevents a call to `Validate()`. I've also tried inserting my own interface with a `Validate()` method and use it as a type constrained, but then failed on the type conversion part.

How can I achieve this without modifying the enums?

```
package main

// imagine i have multiple of those types outside of my control
type FooStatusEnum string

func NewFooStatusEnum(value FooStatusEnum) *FooStatusEnum {
    return &value
}

const (
    FooStatusEnumA FooStatusEnum = "A"
    FooStatusEnumB FooStatusEnum = "B"
    FooStatusEnumC FooStatusEnum = "C"
)

func (m FooStatusEnum) Validate() error {
    return nil
}

func stringToValidatedEnum[E ~string](s string) E {
    e := E(s)
    if err := e.Validate(); err != nil {
        panic(1)
    }
    return e
}

func main() {
    stringToValidatedEnum[FooStatusEnum]("A")
    e := FooStatusEnum("A")
    e.Validate()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a type constraint that both specifies `string` underlying type *and* the `Validate()` method:

```
type enumString interface {
    ~string
    Validate() error
}

func stringToValidatedEnum[E enumString](s string) E {
    e := E(s)
    if err := e.Validate(); err != nil {
        panic(1)
    }
    return e
}
```

Testing it:

```
result := stringToValidatedEnum[FooStatusEnum]("A")
fmt.Printf("%T %v", result, result)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/lcAgSCZcHxi)):

```
main.FooStatusEnum A
```